# How to call an web API in Angular microsoft login?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am working in Angular microsoft login using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular). Here i am calling some webapis from server. Here from frontend i have implemented microsoft login so without sending the token this apis are not working. So how to call this apis without any error.

In my application only after logging in with microsoft everything is working fine but i am having multiple apis to call before login so how to fetch them without logging in.

Here is the code so far i tried:

```
  export const protectedResourceMap:[string, string[]][]= [
    ['https://buildtodoservice.azurewebsites.net/api/todolist', [ 'api://a88bb933-319c-41b5-9f04-eff36d985612/access_as_user' ]],
    ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
];
 

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            MsalModule.forRoot({
                auth: {
                    clientId: 'Your client ID',
                }
            }, {
                protectedResourceMap : protectedResourceMap
            })
        ]
    })
```

Comment: If the APIs only work after login then only call them after the user is logged in. If you want to call them without a logged in user then change the API to support that. If you cannot change the API and cannot change the requirements you are out of luck.

Comment: How to do that before logging in. In my localhost its working fine whereas if i deploy it then i am getting an error.

Comment: Please share the error that you are getting so that I can have a look at it

Comment: I am getting **401 Unauthorized**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **401** error because you have added `user delegated` authentication on your API, you also have to add `Application Permissions` to your App's Service Principle, so that the API is called **on-behalf of your application**:

[image]

Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga) article for more information on giving API permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have added both of them in my API could you please tell me exactly which permissions to add.

Comment: It is as per your code, you have added Graph API `user.read` permission and also add permissions for your api `https://buildtodoservice.azurewebsites.net/api/todolist`. Check this out for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#application-permission-to-microsoft-graph

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: I have added delegated and application permissions in the portal which you have indicated but still that apis are not working until and unless i login to the app.

Comment: Can you create a different SP with only Application permissions enabled and use it?